# Not able to stream content over gigabit switch over WiFI

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares, home-networking

Hello anyone having networking knowledge please assist :)

I have a gigabit tp link switch, tp link wifi 100 MBps router and a PC. Cable internet wire.

All 3 need to be connected so that PC gets Gigabit connectivity and WiFi router gets full 100 Mbps connectivity and all files can be shared from PC over the WiFi router.

1. I have connected my cable internet line to the gigibit switch in port 1
2. Port 2 of switch has PC
3. Port 3 of switch has wifi router which is connected to WAN port

Now my router only supports 100MBps and I dont want spend to get a gigabit router. ( TP link W841N) its costing around Rs 3k and speeds of 100MBps is fine for now.

Now I have added PPPoE interface on router and its able to connect on its own and all WiFi connectivity work.

On PC net is working fine using a dialup PPPoE connection.

Both on PC and WiFi are getting different public IP, now even though net is working, i am not able to see the files which i have shared on my PC on my WiFi devices. All devices are connected via same switch.

now could anyone find the solution..

wifi router lan ip is 198.168.0.1

pc lan ip is: 192.168.1.1

Once both PC and WiFi Router are connected to the net, both have different public IP even though connected via same switch and net connection.

Comment: You don't want multiple public addresses when trying to do this. Can your provide what public addresses you have been assigned? (Minus host info) i.e both have networks starting in (10.0.x.x, 172.16.x.x or 192.168.x.x). Can you provide a diagram of how it's wired? It think it will help you get a better answer.

Comment: Your ISP is incompetent.

Comment: From a safety/best practices POV you need to plug the WAN port of your router into the ISP network, and link a LAN Interface from your router to the gigabit switch. Plug all devices in to gigabit switch.

Comment: ty fr ur reply :) 
https://i.imgur.com/3Iy7tIDl.jpg 
 i have changed the router ip to 192.168.1.2 and lan for now i think is auto ip.

Answer (score 0):

ty fr ur reply :) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czg3K.jpg 
 i have changed the router ip to 192.168.1.2 and lan for now i think is auto ip.

Also if i were to get gigabit router will Asus Rt-Ac58U be good ? for 1080P shared files streaming over WiFI on fire stick and 150Mbps net connection ?